# Python list is not passing as expected while doing recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to solve the[N-Queues](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens/submissions/) 
as following:

```
class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queues = []

    def DFS(self, n, row, col, pie, na, path):
        if row == n:
            print 'current recursion path: ', path
            self.queues.append(path)
            print 'paths within the recursion: ', self.queues
            return 

        for c in range(n):
            if (c not in col) and (c + row not in pie) and (row-c not in na):
                col.add(c)
                pie.add(c+row)
                na.add(row-c)
                # self.queues.append(c)
                # path += str(c)
                path.append(c)
                # print 'row: ', row, 'col: ', c, path
                self.DFS(n, row + 1, col, pie, na, path)
                col.remove(c)
                pie.remove(c+row)
                na.remove(row-c)
                # path = path[:-1]
                path.pop()
            # else:
                # path.pop()
        return None
        # print '\n'

    def solveNQueens(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: List[List[str]]
        """
        col = set()
        pie = set()
        na = set()
        print 'before recursion: ', self.queues
        self.DFS(n, 0, col, pie, na, [])
        print 'after recursion: ', self.queues
        # return self.reslutPrint(n)
```

I got the following print out:

```
before recursion:  []
current recursion path:  [1, 3, 0, 2]
paths within the recursion:  [[1, 3, 0, 2]]
current recursion path:  [2, 0, 3, 1]
paths within the recursion:  [[2, 0, 3, 1], [2, 0, 3, 1]]
after recursion:  [[], []]
```

As you can see, the recursion is getting the correct answer for each path, however, the answer is not appended to the global variable `self.queues` correctly. Can you please let me know why is this happening?

I'm guessing this is due to that when I appended the list to `self.queues`, it's giving the address instead of the actual value to `self.queues`. If so, how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Ian

Comment: replace `self.queues.append(path)` with `self.queues.append(path[:])`. `path[:]` is a copy of the list `path`.

Comment: `self.queues` is not a global variable.  In any even, as pointed out, the problem is that you `self.queues.append(path)` but then proceed to remove all elements from `path` in your for-loop, i.e. `path.pop()`

Comment: Read the following from StackOverflow legends about the way Python name's work: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having isn't with `self.queues`, but rather how you're handling `path`. When you pass `path` it into a function, you're [passing it by assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/1342257), not its value.

Therefore, when you add `path` to `self.queues` and later do `path.pop()`, it is affecting anywhere `path` is referenced, including in `self.queues`.

Here's a simple example of the problem:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> b.pop()
>>> print(a)
[[1, 2]]
```

So, what's the best way to correct this? You could, as others have suggested, *copy* your list before appending it, with `self.queues.append(path[:])`. But I think a closer examination suggests another answer: pass a *new* `path` to each new level of the recursion. Rather than `path.append(c)`, try `self.DFS(n, row + 1, pie, na, path + [c]`. In this way, you're taking a more *functional* approach of immutability (you could go one step further and *enforce* immutability by using an immutable data structure, such as `tuple`). Here's how your code would look with this approach:

```
def DFS(self, n, row, col, pie, na, path):
    if row == n:
        print 'current recursion path: ', path
        self.queues.append(path)
        print 'paths within the recursion: ', self.queues
        return 

    for c in range(n):
        if (c not in col) and (c + row not in pie) and (row-c not in na):
            col.add(c)
            pie.add(c+row)
            na.add(row-c)
            self.DFS(n, row + 1, col, pie, na, path + [c])
            col.remove(c)
            pie.remove(c+row)
            na.remove(row-c)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No it doesn't. But that's not the point. If you `.append` a list and then modify that list, that change will be reflected in the outer list. Try it out: `in_ls = [1,2,3]; out_ls = []; out_ls.append(in_ls); del in_ls[1]; print(out_ls)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't make any mention of immutable objects, so I'm not sure how my answer would lead somewhere there. I've added a link explaining the issue in depth, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, when you append you are putting a list into `self.queues`, it's via the address. But that's not the issue, the issue is you later go on to modify that same object, and so emptying it also means self.queues holds a pointer to an empty list.

You need to make a copy of the path (eg by `self.queues.append(path[:]`) variable, and append that to queues. Or in the general case you can use python's copy moduele (either shallow or deep copy depending on your use case https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)